# SQL Server 2019 Out of memory error message

Tags: crash, out-of-memory, database-migration, sql-server-2019

Last weekend, we successfully migrated a SQL2016 AlwaysOnAG to a SQL 2019 AlwayOnAG. The new server has double the amount of memory (512GB), it's patched to CU12. OS is Windows Server 2019. Last night SQL crashed due to an "out of memory" error. As a result a failover took place. It looks like this error was caused by a rebuild of a columnstore index, because I saw a start of this action, but no completion time (we use the scripts from Ola Hallengren).
This index was already in the SQL2016 environment and no changes have been made since the migration (we're still in a "freeze"). Some things we are using: TDE, memory-optimized tempdb, in-memory tables, resource governor (disabled), polybase (but not used so far). Max memory for SQL is 448GB according to http://sqlmax.chuvash.eu/.
To me, an index rebuild should not result in this error. Any thoughts/ recommendations about this issue?

Comment: This is NOT a virtual machine

Comment: Was it actually using all that memory, or did it crash on much lower memory? Looks like CU13 fixes a bug that *might* be relevant https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5005679-cumulative-update-13-for-sql-server-2019-5c1be850-460a-4be4-a569-fe11f0adc535#bkmk_14209346. Other than that: report it to Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks, I also saw this memory-issue fix (looks like every CU has memory-fixes). However, I want to wait 2 more weeks before I deploy this CU

Comment: I'm guessing memory-optimized tempdb and in-memory tables are what is tripping you up somehow. Was the index rebuild `SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON`? Was the index on an in-memory table?

Comment: It was a columnstore index and yes SORT_IN_TEMPDB=ON

Comment: Well there you have it: The bug does say "Memory Optimized TempDB Metadata keeps consuming memory under VARHEAP: LOB Page Allocator" so if you were using LOB data (`varchar(max)` or `varbinary(max)` or `xml` etc) then I would certainly say you should update your instance. As a workaround turn off `SORT_IN_TEMPDB`

Comment: Thanks, I disabled the SORT_IN_TEMPDB and monitored the memory usage during reindex, which is steady now.